# Can a private Structure(defined in a class) not be used as Return type for a function belonging to same class?

Tags: c++

I am working on a BST. The relevant code is given below:-
This is the class definition:-

```
class BST
{

private:
    struct Leaf
    {
      int val;
      int count;
      Leaf *left,*right;
    };


Leaf *root;  // This is unique for entire class;

public:
   BST()    // Constructor for BST
    {
      root = NULL;
    }

    void Insert(); // Insert in the BST
    Leaf* InsertNode(Leaf *pos,Leaf *node);  // Recursive and Consize function to Insert the node,extention of Insert func
    void Search(); // Search in the BST
    bool SearchNode(Leaf *pos,int val); // Recursive and Consize function to Search the node,extention of Search func
    int Count(Leaf *Node);  // Count the children of a Node
    void Print();  // Print the BST
    void Inorder(Leaf *Node,int indent);
    void Delete(); // Delete a node in BST
    Leaf* DeleteNode(Leaf *pos,int val);  // Recursive and Consize function to Delete the node,extention of Delete func


};
```

This is the definition of the Insert function:-

```
Leaf* BST::InsertNode(Leaf *pos,Leaf *node)
{
    if(pos == NULL)
    {
      return node;
    }
    if(pos->val > node->val)
        pos->left = InsertNode(pos->left,node);
    if(pos->val < node->val)
        pos->right = InsertNode(pos->right,node);   

    return pos;
}
```

I am getting the compilation error:-

```
bst.cpp(81): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
bst.cpp(81): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
bst.cpp(82): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
bst.cpp(82): error C2556: 'int *BST::InsertNode(BST::Leaf *,BST::Leaf *)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'BST::Leaf *BST::InsertNode(BST::Leaf *,BST::Leaf *)'
```

The error is still present even if I make declarion of Structure public.
The error disappears only when I declare the struct outside class.

Can someone please explain what is the reason behind this?

Comment: The established terminology is to use the term "leaf node", or "leaf" for short, for nodes which don't have any children. Naming a type "Leaf" when it doesn't necessarily represent leaf nodes is pretty confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not access control, but rather scoping. `Leaf` is defined in `BST`, so its name is in the `BST` scope:

```
BST::Leaf* BST::InsertNode(BST::Leaf *pos, BST::Leaf *node)
```

Now, being a private type of `BST` places some limitations on how non-friends can access the type. They won't be able to say

```
BST::Leaf* leaf = foo.InsertNode(bar, baz);
```

but they can say

```
auto leaf = foo.InsertNode(bar, baz);
```

On the surface it looks like `BST::Leaf` should be `public`.